# Power supply specifies range of voltage output: how is this possible

Tags: power-supply, voltage

The power supply I bought has an output voltage of "15-24V". I need 19V for my laptop and I couldn't find anything where I could adjust the output voltage to a desired value (like a little screw or something).

[image]

Measuring the voltage gives an output voltage of 20V.

Now I am confused: shouldn't the output voltage be specified more exactly?

Comment: Your imgur link complains about the wrong format what I tried to edit to add your picture.

Comment: @placeholder, you just need to add ".jpg" to the end of the url.

Comment: @ThePhoton Homer Simpson mode on " DOH"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The voltage is programmed by sense resistors in the tips. For example, see [this page](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/laptop-universal-power-adapter,2852-4.html) for some of the sense resistor values used in such Targus universal power supplies. With a little DIY you can program the output voltages as you like, e.g. [see here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/dorkbotpdx-blabber/kensington/dorkbotpdx-blabber/JwdnpggcmPM/uciUBuYTkekJ) for Kensington universal PSUs.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hacking isn't involved. As I said, the voltage is controlled by the tips. But if you want to program it to some combination of voltage and tip not available from Targus then it is a DIY project.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks! So this means the tip basically adjusts the voltage to the desired value by itself? Or do the different tips that come with the adapter all provide a different output voltage so I have to choose the right tip?

Comment: @AlphaOmega When you plug the tip into the power supply it senses the resistor built into the tip, which tells it the desired voltage to output for that tip. Normally the manufacturer lists the laptops that are compatible with each tip (which means that they have both compatible voltage and compatible mating plug).